# problems publishing org files

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I am following the directions given in a [worg](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org-publish-html-tutorial.html) for publishing org files to HTML. This looks like the most vanilla org to HTML publication exercise. As suggested, I eval'ed the following block:

```
    (require 'org-publish)
(setq org-publish-project-alist
      '(
    ("org-notes"
     :base-directory "~/www/"
     :base-extension "org"
     :publishing-directory "~/public_html/"
     :recursive t
     :publishing-function org-publish-org-to-html
     :headline-levels 4             ; Just the default for this project.
     :auto-preamble t
     )
    ("org-static"
     :base-directory "~/www/"
     :base-extension "css\\|js\\|png\\|jpg\\|gif\\|pdf\\|mp3\\|ogg\\|swf"
     :publishing-directory "~/public_html/"
     :recursive t
     :publishing-function org-publish-attachment
     )
    ("org" :components ("org-notes" "org-static"))
       ;; ... add all the components here (see below)...
      ))
```

But when I run `M-x org-publish-project RET org RET`, I get the following error:

```
Symbol's value as variable is void: org-export-html-special-string-regexps
```

Some Googling suggests that this could be due to multiple versions of org installed. I think this isn't the case with me. I have a fresh (1 day old) installation of GNU Emacs on Mac OS X and I subsequently updated to the most recent org-mode using `M-x package-install`.

Any advice?

**edit 1:** Here is the output for `M-x org-version`:

`Org-mode version 8.2.5h (8.2.5h-19-g0ceb68-elpa @ /Users/krishnan/.emacs.d/elpa/org-20140210/)`

**edit 2:** Debug info added:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-variable org-export-html-special-string-regexps)
  org-export-html-convert-special-strings("Kaushik Krishnan")
  org-html-do-expand("Kaushik Krishnan")
  org-html-expand("Kaushik Krishnan")
  org-export-as-html(4 (:buffer-will-be-killed t :base-directory "~/www/" :base-extension "org" :publishing-directory "~/public_html/" :recursive t :publishing-function org-publish-org-to-html :headline-levels 4 :auto-preamble t) nil nil "/Users/krishnan/public_html/")
  org-publish-org-to("html" (:base-directory "~/www/" :base-extension "org" :publishing-directory "~/public_html/" :recursive t :publishing-function org-publish-org-to-html :headline-levels 4 :auto-preamble t) "/Users/krishnan/www/index.org" "/Users/krishnan/public_html/")
  org-publish-org-to-html((:base-directory "~/www/" :base-extension "org" :publishing-directory "~/public_html/" :recursive t :publishing-function org-publish-org-to-html :headline-levels 4 :auto-preamble t) "/Users/krishnan/www/index.org" "/Users/krishnan/public_html/")
  org-publish-file("/Users/krishnan/www/index.org" ("org-notes" :base-directory "~/www/" :base-extension "org" :publishing-directory "~/public_html/" :recursive t :publishing-function org-publish-org-to-html :headline-levels 4 :auto-preamble t) t)
  #[(project) "\306@!\210A\307  \310\"\307  \311\"\307  \312\"\206\313\307  \314\"\206#\315\307 \316\"\206- \307    \317\"\2068!\"\307  \320\"\307  \321\"\322\n\"#\323$\203X\324\325!\210\203a
\f\"\210#\211A#@\211$\203x\326$\327#\210\202a\307   \330\"\203\222\331\307  \332\"!\210\326\333\334\307 \332\"\"\327#\210\203\233\324\335!\210\336 .\207" [project project-plist exclude-regexp sitemap-p sitemap-filename sitemap-function org-publish-initialize-cache plist-get :exclude :auto-sitemap :sitemap-filename "sitemap.org" :sitemap-function org-publish-org-sitemap :sitemap-date-format :sitemap-file-entry-format :preparation-function :completion-function org-publish-get-base-files nil run-hooks preparation-function org-publish-file t :makeindex org-publish-index-generate-theindex :base-directory expand-file-name "theindex.org" completion-function org-publish-write-cache-file org-publish-sitemap-date-format org-sitemap-date-format org-publish-sitemap-file-entry-format org-sitemap-file-entry-format files file] 6](("org-notes" :base-directory "~/www/" :base-extension "org" :publishing-directory "~/public_html/" :recursive t :publishing-function org-publish-org-to-html :headline-levels 4 :auto-preamble t))
  mapc(#[(project) "\306@!\210A\307 \310\"\307  \311\"\307  \312\"\206\313\307  \314\"\206#\315\307 \316\"\206- \307    \317\"\2068!\"\307  \320\"\307  \321\"\322\n\"#\323$\203X\324\325!\210\203a
\f\"\210#\211A#@\211$\203x\326$\327#\210\202a\307   \330\"\203\222\331\307  \332\"!\210\326\333\334\307 \332\"\"\327#\210\203\233\324\335!\210\336 .\207" [project project-plist exclude-regexp sitemap-p sitemap-filename sitemap-function org-publish-initialize-cache plist-get :exclude :auto-sitemap :sitemap-filename "sitemap.org" :sitemap-function org-publish-org-sitemap :sitemap-date-format :sitemap-file-entry-format :preparation-function :completion-function org-publish-get-base-files nil run-hooks preparation-function org-publish-file t :makeindex org-publish-index-generate-theindex :base-directory expand-file-name "theindex.org" completion-function org-publish-write-cache-file org-publish-sitemap-date-format org-sitemap-date-format org-publish-sitemap-file-entry-format org-sitemap-file-entry-format files file] 6] (("org-notes" :base-directory "~/www/" :base-extension "org" :publishing-directory "~/public_html/" :recursive t :publishing-function org-publish-org-to-html :headline-levels 4 :auto-preamble t) ("org-static" :base-directory "~/www/" :base-extension "css\\|js\\|png\\|jpg\\|gif\\|pdf\\|mp3\\|ogg\\|swf" :publishing-directory "~/public_html/" :recursive t :publishing-function org-publish-attachment)))
  org-publish-projects((("org" :components ("org-notes" "org-static"))))
  org-publish-project(("org" :components ("org-notes" "org-static")) nil)
  call-interactively(org-publish-project record nil)
  command-execute(org-publish-project record)
  execute-extended-command(nil "org-publish-project")
  call-interactively(execute-extended-command nil nil)
```

Comment: Hey @artscan, here is the output: `Org-mode version 8.2.5h (8.2.5h-19-g0ceb68-elpa @ /Users/krishnan/.emacs.d/elpa/org-20140210/)`

Comment: Switch on `M-x toggle-debug-on-error` and give debug info.

Comment: Try to change `org-publish-org-to-html` to `org-html-publish-to-html`. `org-publish-org-to-html` and `org-export-html-special-string-regexps` are symbols from old versions.

Comment: @artscan, debug info added

Comment: @artscan, you're right! Switching to `org-html-publish-to-html` solves the problem!

Comment: @artscan, I added your solution as a community wiki answer, so the question doesn't appear unanswered. Feel free to post your solution as a proper answer in order to get credit for it, and I'll delete my answer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From the comments: changing

```
 :publishing-function org-publish-org-to-html
```

to

```
 :publishing-function org-html-publish-to-html
```

solves the problem.  `org-publish-org-to-html` is an obsolete name.